# adapt function to rolling

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe with daily OHLC data and I'm calculating the "up/down volume" as described e.g. here: https://www.investors.com/how-to-invest/investors-corner/top-stocks-under-accumulation-use-the-up-down-volume-ratio-to-find-the-best-prospects/

It is looking at the last 50 days and then divides the volume of the up days by the volume of the down days:

```
def func_updown(df):
    tmp=df[-50:].copy(deep = True)
    tmp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    tmp['Change']=tmp['Close'].pct_change()
    u_d = round(tmp[tmp['Change']>0]['Volume'].sum()/tmp[tmp['Change']<0]['Volume'].sum(),2)
    return(u_d)
```

As expected, this gives me just the current result.
However, I would like to see the trend and ideally add a new column to my dataframe with the past values. E.g. yesterdays up down value would be calculated with a shifted window of 50 days.
I guess I would have to do this with "rolling" somehow, but couldn't figure it out.
Any hints are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the stock market, but I think I have an idea about what you are trying to do.

So here is it.

Suppose you have this dataframe (numbers are made up). I assume each day corresponds to a single row in the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Close': [5,7,2,6,5,3,7,4,2,7,9],
    'Volume': [12,46,32,24,14,63,73,45,15,16,84]
})
```

Add a column of the pct change to it.

```
df['Pct_Change'] = df['Close'].pct_change().fillna(0)
```

Copy the column `Volume` to columns `VolumeDown` and `VolumeUp` and then set the values that don't belong there equal to `0`. This means `VolumeDown` should contain only the volumes that correspond to a negative percentage change, and `VolumeUp` should contain only the volumes corresponding to a positive percentage change.

```
df['VolumeDown'] = df['Volume']
df['VolumeUp'] = df['Volume']

df.loc[df['Pct_Change'] > 0, 'VolumeDown'] = 0
df.loc[df['Pct_Change'] < 0, 'VolumeUp'] = 0
```

Then create the `VolumeDownRolling` and `VolumeUpRolling` columns using `rolling`. In your case you should fill in `50` as the window size, but I am keeping it at `2` for the demonstration.

```
df['VolumeDownRolling'] = df['VolumeDown'].rolling(2).sum().fillna(0)
df['VolumeUpRolling'] = df['VolumeUp'].rolling(2).sum().fillna(0)
```

Now you can compute your `UpDownRolling`.

```
df['UpDownRolling'] = df['VolumeUpRolling']/df['VolumeDownRolling']

df
```

[image]

**Word of caution.**

You should be careful about the way your dataframe is ordered. E.g. from most recent to past values or the other way around. It might be needed to reorder your df or adjust the rolling default parameters to fit your data.

Comment: Thanks DataFace! I like your methodical step-by-step approach,but I got different results. I guess it depends on how/when the sum is calculated and divided.
my solution is a bit clumsy:
`ud_result=[]

    for i in range(10):
        if i == 0:
            tmp=df_daily[-50:].copy(deep = True)
        else:
            tmp=df_daily[-50-i:i*-1].copy(deep = True)
        tmp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        tmp['Change']=tmp['Close'].pct_change()
        u_d = round(tmp[tmp['Change']>0]['Volume'].sum()/tmp[tmp['change']<0]['Volume'].sum(),2)
        ud_result.append(u_d)`

Comment: `df_daily[-50-i:i*-1]` shouldn't this be `df_daily[-50-i:i-1]` without the multiplication sign `*`? Otherwise you are getting smaller and smaller windows eacht time. First iteration `[-50:0]`, second iteration `[-51:-1]`, third iteration `[-52:-4]`, fourth `[-53:-6]`, etc. I think this is not what you're aiming.

Comment: But isn't i counting from 1 to 10, so I get -50, -50-1:-1, -50-2:-2, -53:-3 and so on?

Comment: ah, yes my bad, it was late apparently :)